# CSS Display Grid Height Issues. Is 3998px the max height for a grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am having an issue where the grid will only expand it height to 3998px.

Even if I hardcode the height of the div that is set to display:grid, the div will get larger but will not render the grid items that are lower than 3998px.

3998px seems like a lot but the site contains large photo galleries.

On desktop this isn't a problem as the ever expanding columns allow for that height never to be hit.

But on mobile it becomes an issue has users can't see their images if they are towards the bottom of list.

Below is the CSS I am using for the grid.  Also a link to the site that is having this issue..for visual: http://smpl.city/events.php?eid=799

```css
.events-page .grid {
    background-color: #000;
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 2px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-auto-rows: 2px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 7em;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked your site on multiple browsers? Is the problem happening on all browsers?

Comment: I did not understand what the problem is. Explain on the pictures.

Comment: why even give the grid an explicit `height`??